# Commemorative wines for a particular movie?

Tags: wine, pairing

Not long ago, I read this article ([FRANCIS FORD COPPOLA WINERY UNVEILS WINES TO BE POURED AT 2017 ACADEMY AWARDS® CEREMONY & GOVERNORS BALL](https://www.oscars.org/sites/oscars/files/89th-gb-francis-ford-coppola-wines.pdf)) and it got me thinking if there exists a wine that commemorates a particular movie and could be paired with it?

Pairing beer with a particular movie is quite commonplace, but commemorative wines that could be paired to a particular movie is much more rare.

Here is a beer example of what I am trying to convey, but I am interested in wine only: [The Hobbit Series of Beers ships this week, coming very soon.](http://beerpulse.com/2014/08/the-hobbit-series-of-beers-ships-this-week-coming-very-soon-3434/)

[image: Gollum Precious Pils]

> [Gollum Precious Pils](http://beerpulse.com/beer/the-hobbit-gollum-precious-pils/): A strong Imperial Pils, with flavors as smooth and crafty as Gollum himself. Like the ring which Gollum pursued for the rest of his life, his “precious” pils, if your quest leads you to it, could extend your life too! (at least we’d like to think so) It will, at a minimum, make your journey a little more enjoyable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wine and movie pairing, although not a very popular item these days, some people seem to be into it.

Here are a few examples, for what they are worth.

**Silence of the Lambs** (1991) can be paired with **Chianti** and **Suit Yourself Pinot Grigio**.

> Alamo Drafthouse is releasing two wines that pay tribute to the classic killer chiller: Cannibal Chianti and Suit Yourself Pinot Grigio.
>
> Italian-grown Cannibal Chianti is a 85% Sangiovese blend with Canaiolo and Malvasia del Chianti, a DOCG wine from a vineyard between Florence and Sienna. Alamo notes that it has “savory plum and tobacco leaf notes.” Suit Yourself Pinot Grigio — a reference to “Lambs” killer Buffalo Bill’s penchant for wearing suits made of women’s skin — is a California wine from the Central Coast and inland vineyards with notes of “tropical peach and Mexican limes with just a hint of honey.” - [Silence of the Lambs’ Wines From Alamo Drafthouse: Quaff Some Cannibal Chianti](http://variety.com/2013/film/news/silence-of-the-lambs-wines-from-alamo-drafthouse-quaff-some-cannibal-chianti-1200489046/)

One must admit that Hannibal Lecter is one sick dude.

> What most people seem to remember about Silence of the Lambs is not when Hannibal Lecter triumphs while shooting two FBI agents, but when Lecter tries to scare off FBI trainee Foster. Lecter says, "A census taker once tried to test me. I ate his liver with some fava beans and a nice **Chianti**." - [Wines Made Famous by the Movies](https://www.vivino.com/wine-news/article-wines-made-famous-by-the-movies)

**Frankenstein** (1931) or any Frankenstein movie may be paired with Francis Coppola Director’s **Frankenstein Cabernet Sauvignon** 2014 California.

> "The Monster" is Boris Karloff's signature film role, and much like a finely crafted bottle of wine, his performance is the result of dedication, study and collaboration with other expert filmmakers.Prepare to be stirred by Dr. Frankenstein's creation and this thrilling Cabernet Sauvignon. - [Movie & Wine Pairing](http://tcmwineclub.com/francis-coppola-directors%20frankenstein-cabernet-sauvignon-2014/)

If you are a **Cleopatra** fan you may try a blend of Zinfandel and Pinot Noir called **Cleopatra** 2014 California.

> Inspired by the legendary allure of the Queen of the Nile, Cleopatra’s namesake red showcases the bounty of California’s stellar 2014 vintage. It’s a bramble- and spice-packed blend of Zinfandel and Pinot Noir, masterfully blended with California rarities like Mourvèdre, Alicante Bouschet and Barbera and more. Winemaker Rob McNeill, of Sonoma’s famed Don Sebastiani & Sons, gave this tempting potion further intrigue with a little oak aging. As you’ll discover, there’s (still) no resisting Cleopatra. - [Movie & Wine Pairing](https://www.vivino.com/wine-news/article-wines-made-famous-by-the-movies)

Of coarse **James Bond** is quite unique in his wine pairs of his 22 episodes, so I will give only three examples here:

> “On Her Majesty’s Secret Service”: This is the first of two 007 movies in which the spy truly falls in love, so let’s go with something romantic, pink bubbles: the very-berry-ish, refined Schramsberg Brut Rosé.
>
> “Diamonds Are Forever”: My favorite Bond wine moment ever is when he uses two assassins’ ignorance about Bordeaux to out and wipe out the dastardly duo. So the tippling tout is the earthy but elegant Chateau D’Argadens Bordeaux Superiore.
>
> Goldfinger”: For me (and countless others), this is the perfect Bond film: nonpareil villain, thug and “Bond girls.” So we need a near-perfect wine; let’s splurge and go with the always-stellar Chateau de Beaucastel Châteauneuf-du-Pape. - [What wine goes with each James Bond movie?](http://What%20wine%20goes%20with%20each%20James%20Bond%20movie?)

One is able to see more wine and movie parings [here](http://tcmwineclub.com/wines-movies/) with such titles as the West Side Story or movies of Alfred Hitchcock or Orson Wells and many more.

[image: Orson Welles Signature Selection Merlot 2013]

[Orson Welles Signature Selection Merlot 2013](http://tcmwineclub.com/wines-movies/)

Answer (score 3):

If I am completely off the track here, tell me and I will delete my answer - but I will have a bash at this.

I found some information [Here](http://www.decanter.com/tag/wine-films/), at decanter.com.

> **Wine films**
>
> There are several well-known films based on the drinking or making of
>   wine or the wine industry itself. They range from American
>   comedy-drama Bottle Shock (featuring Alan Rickman as wine expert
>   Steven Spurrier), buddy-movie Sideways and book adaptation A Good Year
>   to smaller pictures such as the controversial Mondovino, mockumentary
>   Corked and French hit Vagabond.
>
> Individual wines have also featured on the big screen including
>   Chateau Margaux in Withnail & I and Sherlock Holmes, Chateau Latour in
>   Monty Python’s Meaning of Life, Chateau Angelus in James Bond Casino
>   Royale and Veuve Clicquot in Casablanca.
>
> In May 2012 it was announced The Billionaire’s Vinegar is to be turned
>   into a motion picture starring Brad Pitt.

Comment: Hey Dougal, thanks so much for your interest and answer to this question, but I believe that the your response deals with wine documentaries more than commemorative wines about a particular film.

Comment: I did wonder, would it be better, (less clutter on the site), if I removed my answer?  It's not a problem.